# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, asp.net-controls

Afternoon All,

I have a dropdown list which extracts data from my SQL database and gives the users two options to choose from (Weekly / Monthly). The database has an ID for each of these.  Weekly is set to 1 and Monthly is set to 2.  This drop down is linked to a gridview which extracts / displays the data based on the selected item.  All of this works perfectly fine.

This issue i have is that i want to add some code in my Page_ load event to populate a text box with the selected item. I would also like to set the dropdownlist as default to weekly when a users access thie page.   i thought that the two following bits of code would work but i get the messege 'Input string was not in a correct format'.

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'This works fine
    lblTodaysDate.Text = GetDate()


    'I thought i could complete an If Statement to get the text box to work.
    If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = 1 Then
        txtMeeting.Text = "SMC Weekly Meeting"
    Else
        txtMeeting.Text = "SMC Monthly Meeting"
    End If


End Sub
```

Im new to .net but have read that i might need to convert my int to a string?

Any help in advance would be much appriechiated.

Regards
Betty.

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: You say that `lblTodaysDate.Text = GetDate()` works fine, but what _is_ `GetDate()`? To get the current date, you simply need `Date.Now.ToShortDateString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that your value is numeric, if it is, then convert it to an integer, and compare it to `1`:

```
If IsNumeric(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) AndAlso CInt(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)=1
    txtMeeting.Text = "SMC Weekly Meeting"
Else
    txtMeeting.Text = "SMC Monthly Meeting"
End If
```

Comment: many thanks for tyour help this works a treat as the selected value is numeric and not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Just try enclosing the desired value in quotes, like this:

```
If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "1" Then
    txtMeeting.Text = "SMC Weekly Meeting"
Else
    txtMeeting.Text = "SMC Monthly Meeting"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check for `IsPostBack` otherwise the ddl SelectValue would be reset

NB: My Vb.Net is a bit rusty

ie

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Me.IsPostBack Then

        'This works fine
        lblTodaysDate.Text = GetDate()

        'I thought i could complete an If Statement to get the text box to work.
        If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "1" Then
            txtMeeting.Text = "SMC Weekly Meeting"
        Else
            txtMeeting.Text = "SMC Monthly Meeting"
        End If
    Else
        ' Put your code to populate the ddl here


    End If
End Sub
```